# Trying to make a video autoplay on google but I cant

Tags: video, plugins, slider, autoplay

This is my code:

```
<video style="object-fit: cover; 
background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; 
line-height: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; 
font-size: 18px; display: block; visibility: inherit; 
opacity: 1;" class="" loop="" preload="auto">

    <source src="https://italianbeauty.com.br/wp-content/
    uploads/2018/11/TV-New-Impact-1.mp4" type="video/mp4" 
    style="transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; 
    line-height: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; 
    font-size: 16px;">

</video>
```

I need to insert:

```
 oncanplay="this.muted=true"
```

between:

```
<video(...)
```

...and...

```
(...)style
```

...but I can't because I can't edit it with HTML, because this is a plugin thing made by Slider Revolution for wordpress. On Firefox, it autoplays fine, but in Chrome it doesn't.